# Merge "exegisis" tag into "exegesis"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

When posting this morning, I noticed that we've got an active "exegesis" tag, but there's also a tag for "exegisis" which appears to be an altered spelling of it.  (There are some Google hits for that spelling, but nothing very authoritative.  And, some of them even use both spellings on the same page.)

Should we merge these?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for noticing that; I've merged [exegisis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegisis) into [exegesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exegesis).

Comment: And I've created a synonym so it can't pop up again